# Selecting a random row from postgresql database is returning "None"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am using Python 3, psycopg2 and trying to retrieve a single random row from my database if the scanned_status = 'false' but it is returning 'None'. My connection to the database is fine. Could somebody please help me with the sql. I have 3 columns: network_number, scanned_status, number_of_scans.

Here is my sql statement

```
def random_network_number():
    """ Retrieve a random network number from the database """
    sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM ip_store WHERE (scanned_status = false) 
    OFFSET floor(random() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_store)) LIMIT 1;"
    network_number = execute_sql_statement(sql_statement)
    output_information(network_number)
    return network_number
```

Output

```
[ * ] None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the Python script. I created a function using the library Psycopg2 and the function was missing the fetchall() method which is what returns the results of a query. When writing to a database you must use commit(). When retrieving you must use fetchall().

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of your SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM ip_store WHERE (scanned_status = false) ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

I have a similar use case that has alway returned a record using the ORDER BY random() method.

I believe the problem with your original SQL is that you are using the count of ALL records to calculate your OFFSET and then applying it to a filtered query.  I bet your OFFSET is greater than the number of filtered rows.  The ORDER BY random() eliminates that problem.

Comment: It is still returning None

Comment: The number of rows in the database is around 13.6 million and every one is set to false.

Comment: If that is the case, I would check and see if your Python script is causing the problem.  Switch the SQL to something like "SELECT * FROM ip_store LIMIT 1;" that you know will return you a record.  I am not an expert with Python and psycopg2 so there may be a problem there that I can't see.